# Calling VS 2008 refactoring methods through command line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I want to create a simple batch file that would perform some Visual Studio 2008 refactoring tasks on some files. For example, I would like to call the **Refactor.ExtractInferface** command on a given file.

Can I do this from the command line? Is there a better way (I am sure there is) of doing this?

Thanks,

H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to run the standard refactoring commands from the Command line.  The command line of Visual Studio really only gives you access to build capabilities and not much else.  The simplest way to automate actions like refactoring is via a macro which is not available at the command line.

A macro though is likely you're best choice.  It can easily call into the refactoring commands and can be automated to a high degree.  It does require Visual Studio to be open though and that might invalidate your requirements.